# Extract sentences from HTML in PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, text-extraction

I'm doing a PHP project (using Codeigniter) on text summarization and for that I need to extract sentences from content of a Rich TextBox (this content includes tags). Therefore **is there a proper method or Codeigniter library to extract sentences from a content containing HTML tags**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A php function [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) should help you. It returns string without php and html tags. If you just need to count sentences, you could do **count(explode(". ", $text))** The delimiter is a typical end of a sentence.

Plain simple and limited, but doesn't require any libraries.

Comment: Thanks.. explode(". ", $text) can be used. Also it needs a little modification to check whether the "." represents an end of line or anything else such as a "." in fractional numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This technique is called as web-scraping

Have a look at [this](http://anchetawern.github.io/blog/2013/08/07/getting-started-with-web-scraping-in-php/)